# Laravel 5.2 check queued jobs before add new one

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue

My Goal - check, if job already in queue with specified arguments.
Let's say, I added job for user id 1.
After that another admin wants to add same job for user id 1.
How to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the status of the user to a Queued status when the job is queued.

Before you push a user to a job, check if ID already exists with status = Queued, if so don't queue it.

Don't know what you already have, code wise, but here is an example:

In one of my own projects it looked like this

```
$oCampaignCustomer->status = ModelCampaignCustomer::STATUS_INVITE_EMAIL_QUEUED;
$oCampaignCustomer->save();
```

Where `$oCampaignCustomer` is a model. 
You can also do query like

```
DB::table('forms')
->where('campaign_customer_id', $id)
->update(['status' => '1']);
```

to update the status, preform a check on the status before you use this update

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tomorrow and reply with results.

Comment: And sadly that **tomorrow** never came back.

Comment: Your approach works fine, but this is still looks like a crutch.

Comment: @OlegShakhov True, Thank god this is 3 years old and I've learned to make much better code by now

Comment: You can update your question with better solution if You want)